# Using Multiple tailwind configs in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, gatsby

I am creating an app in Gatsby. I'm new to react library so having some trouble. In my Gatsby app, I've successfully built pages with Tailwind as a CSS framework. I followed the following tailwind article to set up Tailwind - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/gatsby

Now I want to use different tailwind configs for different pages. I've tried achieving the same using tailwind built-in `@config` option but for some reasons it's not working.

In my `global.css` I included the primary tailwind config as follows -

```
@config "../../tailwind.author.config.js"

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Then I included the secondary config in other CSS files. Besides passing a different config through `@config`, the app continues to use the global tailwind included in `gatsby-browser.js`. If I remove tailwind config from `gatsby-browser.js`, the entire app ui breaks.